# Automate login, navigation and parse of web pages in React Native

Tags: react-native, html-parsing

I would like to get information from a specific website (https) from within a react native app.
For that, I need to:

1. Open and Login to the web page (https)
2. Make a simple navigation (known tag in html)
3. Parse the resulting page for data.
4. Present the data in a React native component (not webUI).

Any idea what would be the best way to do it?

10x,
EyalS

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do:

1. Use the [following tutorial](https://hackernoon.com/using-core-node-js-modules-in-react-native-apps-64acd4d07140]) to use [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) to wrap [Zombie.js](https://github.com/assaf/zombie#browser) within a react-native app.
2. Navigate with Zombie.js to the data that you are seeking.
3. Display the data.

Happy coding.